# cannot get my birthday and email from facebook graph API v2.5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

Api version 2.5, I'm asked about birthday and email when logging into this app.

```
{my-id}/permissions
```

returns

```
 {
     "permission": "user_birthday",
     "status": "granted"
  },
```

among data, but then

```
{my_id}?access_token=my_token&fields=birthday,email
```

doesn't return birthday or email

is there any other place where it could be disabled?

Comment: Can you test your app using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and check if it returns the birthday there?

Comment: @AlexPalcuie it does return birthday, not email though, what is the difference if I do ask and agree about birthday and email when logging to my app?

Comment: Well, the flow is that you at first request those permissions from the user, he agrees to them and then you have access to those properties. Try to replace the access token in the API Explorer with the real one you use in the app and see if you can do the same queries.

Comment: Your email address has to be verified, that the case?